# UIScroll animation is interrupted by NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate processing

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When the keyboardWillHide, I scroll the tableView to a specified point. The code is below. This works well.

Now, I implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. I set it "on" by setting `fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;` The scroll animation is interrupted. The NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is calling `[tableView beginUpdates]`, which I think is causing the interruption on the tableView animation.

How can I prevent the scroll animation from being interrupted and still implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [screen setHidden:YES];
    [suggestView setHidden:YES];

    [_tableView setContentOffset:origin animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can't do animations in keyboardWillHide. You shouldn't do any animation in any "WILL" event.